# getting google pubsub status in json format

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I know https://status.cloud.google.com/ will fetch status from all google cloud services. Is there anyway I can pull status only for google pubsub in json format?

And also is configuring 'uptime check' in stackdriver monitoring with this url https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=project_id url valid?

Thanks,
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

I tried the obvious `curl -H 'Accept: application/json' https://status.cloud.google.com/`, but I still received an HTML response.

They *do* have https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents.json. Does that produce what you're after?

Comment: Yes that output is html only. And Incidents.json  gives incidents from all google cloud services. I think it will not give pubsub status.